# How can i validate a model without binding it with the action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, model-validation

I am updating database values using an action method but I am using ajax call to send updated values into that method so I am not binding model with this method so how can I validate the model for this action method such as I am not binding this with my method?

```
public ActionResult Update(int id, double? value)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json("Not valid model");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
         var oldTag = db.Tags.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
         List<UpdatedData> updatedDatas = new List<UpdatedData> {
         new UpdatedData
         {
             Id=id,
             OldTagValue=oldTag.TagValue,
             NewTagValue=value,
             TagName = oldTag.TagName
         }
        };
            obj.updatedDatas = new List<UpdatedData>();
            obj.updatedDatas.AddRange(updatedDatas);
            return PartialView("_Update_Confirmation", obj);
        }
        return View("Index");

    }
```

Comment: One solid option is using `FluentValidation` Nuget package. https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/

Comment: Siavash i think fluentValidation is for asp.net core

Comment: Not necessarily, but it has built-in integration for Asp.Net core. But you can use it in any project for the most part.

Comment: You can validate before the ajax call in jquery/ javascript etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can change `Update` method

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public double? value { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
public ActionResult Update(ProfileViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json("Not valid model");
    }
 //...
}
```

> The sample **DataAnnotations** model binder will fill model state with validation errors taken from the **DataAnnotations** attributes on your model.

Comment: I am not passing the model as a parameter to the method instead of that I am passing two values using ajax call.